# Assign 3 values to Variable from Text File

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file with the following format:

```
123, 456, [45,45,90]
20,  19,  [4,67,95]
120, 45,  [50,20,20]
```

I am wondering what the best way would be to assign a variable to each comma separated value.  For example,

```
x, y, vec = [], [], []
for i, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
    x.append(float(line.split(',')[0]))
    y.append(float(line.split(',')[1]))
    vec.append(np.array(line.split(',')[2]))

>>> IDEAL OUTPUT
x = [123,20,120]
y = [456, 19, 45]
vec = [[45,45,90],[4,67,95],[50,20,20]]
```

for the variable, `vec`, what should I edit to the above code to perhaps make the variable `vec` into a numpy array?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `vec = np.array(vec)` should work (just after the loop is done)

Comment: you don't need to split the line three times, just write it once after the for loop, line=line.split(','), then append to x, y, and vec.

Comment: Parsing a string "[4,67,95]" is messy.  You have to remove the `[]` before you can split and convert the strings to numbers.  Or use `eval` to turn the string into a list.

Comment: If the input didn't include brackets but just five entries separated by commas, what would you recommend in that situation? Thanks.